# Is there a function in pyspark that can convert string (JSON) column into multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has multiple columns and one of the metrics column datatype is in string format. This column data looks like the below, I need to convert it into multiple columns. I tried using spark rdd map function, it shows a type value error.

Schema :column1,

column2,

metrics string

Sample data :

```
[{"name": "ABC","kt":

[{"name": "AB-1",

"values":

[{"date": "2021-05-21 08:04:56.000", "value":0.05520880298702948},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:05:56.000", "value": 0.6873692705340528},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:06:56.000", "value": 1.0036619131928861},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:07:56.000", "value": 0.7431644238409444},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:08:56.000", "value": 0.9845464929057735},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:09:56.000", "value": 1.0010811066472702},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:10:56.000", "value": 1.0009814513959714},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:11:56.000", "value": 1.001614167307074},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:12:56.000", "value": 1.001766291527917},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:13:56.000", "value": 0.5865639742905218},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:14:56.000", "value": 1.0015836161251768},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:15:56.000", "value": 0.3571215446400451}]},

{"name": "BC-2",

"values":

[{"date": "2021-05-21 08:04:56.000", "value": 0.14044187962813096},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:05:56.000", "value": 0.7565445799225486},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:06:56.000", "value": 1.0017136900856412},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:07:56.000", "value": 1.001730692743276},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:08:56.000", "value": 1.0010340874676533},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:09:56.000", "value": 1.0007168399510786},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:10:56.000", "value": 1.0017091878186537},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:11:56.000", "value": 1.0004370714489406},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:12:56.000", "value": 1.0015819812456357},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:13:56.000", "value": 0.7370171481823211},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:14:56.000", "value": 1.001703540193026},

{"date": "2021-05-21 08:15:56.000", "value": 0.5519119341514123}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to check if your JSON is indeed formatted correctly as the sample data given is not valid JSON.

Assuming your intention is to flatten the nested JSON structure into rows datetime and values you can try something similar to this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# example valid JSON 
json = """
[
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "kt": [
            {
                "name": "AB-1",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "date": "2021-05-21 08:04:56.000",
                        "value": 0.05520880298702948
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "BC-2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "date": "2021-05-21 08:04:56.000",
                        "value": 0.14044187962813096
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
"""

json_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, json)],['id', 'json'])

# define the schema for the dataframe
schema = t.ArrayType(
    t.StructType([
        t.StructField('name', t.StringType()),
        t.StructField('kt', t.ArrayType(
            t.StructType([
                t.StructField('name', t.StringType()),
                t.StructField('values', t.ArrayType(
                    t.StructType([
                        t.StructField('date', t.TimestampType()),
                        t.StructField('value', t.DoubleType())
                    ])
                ))
            ])
        ))
    ])
)

# select the string value in the 'json' column using the defined schema
df = json_df.select(
    f.from_json(f.col('json'), schema).alias('json')
)

# flatten the nested structure to expose date and properties as columns
df.select(
    f.explode('json')
).select(
    f.col('col.name').alias('name_0'),
    f.explode('col.kt')
).select(
    'name_0',
    'col.*'
).select(
    'name_0',
    f.col('name').alias('name_1'),
    f.explode('values')
).select(
    'name_0',
    'name_1',
    'col.*'
).show()
```

Expected output:

```
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|name_0|name_1|               date|              value|
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   ABC|  AB-1|2021-05-21 08:04:56|0.05520880298702948|
|   ABC|  BC-2|2021-05-21 08:04:56|0.14044187962813096|
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank yo so much @noah Irzinger, it's worked . In the step(# flatten the nested structure to expose date and properties as columns)
, is there any way I can add all other columns in dataframe instead of specifying all columns manually

Answer (score -1):

```
df = spark.read.json("<Your JSON file path>")

df.write.option("header","true").csv("<Your CSV file path>")
```

Comment: Reading json files without schema imposition risks losing data, because spark engine uses a sample of json files to infer the schema, and if a field doesn't exist in the sample, it's gonna be drop when reading all files.